# Templated function not called

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have overloaded a function in my string class, however, it never gets called. Why?

```
template <class T>
class StringT {
public:
    void assign(const T* ptr);
    template <size_t N> void assign(const T(&ptr)[N]);
};

int main() {
    StringT<char> str;
    str.assign("Hello World"); //calls "void assign(const T* ptr)" although type is (const char[12])
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't have expected it.  I made a slightly more complex example here: http://cpp.sh/7hnfk which agrees with Microsoft's assertion that auto s = "thing"; will result in a const char * (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx) by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For more reference, some specific references to the Standard are:

> **13.3.3 Best viable function**
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then...
>
> - F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization...

In this case, the non-templated function is (obviously) not a function template specialization and the conversion of `"Hello World"` to `char const*` is not worse than to `const char[N]`, per the ranking rules defined in the Table in the "Standard conversion sequences" section.  According to that Table, both `No conversions required` and `Array-to-pointer conversion` are considered an exact match in the context of overload resolution.  Likewise, if the templated overloads are changed to a non-template overload (i.e., as `void assign(const T(&ptr)[12]);`), then compilation of `str.assign("Hello World");` will fail due to an ambiguous call.

To make sure the non-template function isn't considered for overload, there is the following note under the "Explicit template argument specification" section:

> Note: An empty template argument list can be used to indicate that a given use refers to a specialization of a function template even when a non-template function (8.3.5) is visible that would otherwise be used.

So, you can use `str.assign<>("Hello World");` for that.

Comment: thank you for this clarification. Could you also post a link to that standard?

Comment: The Standard releases aren't freely-available from what I can tell, but you can get the draft copies at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/ under the [latest publicly available draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) link.  Not sure if there's a better way, though...

Comment: I'm still trying to reconcile this with the fact that:     
    StringT<char> str;
    char hw_array[] = "Hello World";
    str.assign(hw_array);
calls the template version

Comment: @Arunas, that's a good question.  According to g++ 6.1, it thinks that the identity conversion sequence is better (i.e., ranked higher) than the (non-const) `char[]` to `char const*` conversion sequence; i.e., when the non-templated `void assign(const T(&ptr)[12]);` signature is presented, there is no compile failure due to ambiguity.  Also, the `char const*` version is selected when passing a `const char[]` when the template version is also available.  As to exactly why it's determining those rankings, I haven't parsed yet.

Answer (score 3):

When there is a choice compiler chooses most specialized function. When there is a non-template function than it is treated as more specialized than any template function

Details [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_117.html)

If you want to keep non-template function but forcibly call template one try

```
str.template assign("Hello World");
```

Comment: may depend on the compiler, but if the const T* version is commented out, the other is called instead.  I don't see any interesting errors.

Comment: @Arunas I edited my answer, so our comments are now irrelevant. I deleted mine

Comment: Is there any way to make the compiler call the template function?

Comment: @Philinator - check out my example (in a comment to your question).  I'm not convinced that this answer is correct, since if you declare a variable to be an array of char, your templated method is called preferentially.

Comment: @Philinator I edited my answer to address your question

Comment: @Arunas In your example _"Constuctor taking pointer"_ is involved, which doesn't exist in OP's code

Comment: @mvidelgauz that's true, but the assign() methods are there.  The constructors only extend the example.

Comment: @Arunas we see that constructor is actually called. what happens if you remove it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115629/discussion-between-mvidelgauz-and-arunas).